# Using .env file with release binary

Tags: macos, rust, release, dotenv, .env

When building a rust binary with `cargo build --release`, the binary is perfectly generated inside `/target/release`, however I get a message that it cannot load env variables.

I then copied the .env file from the project to the same directory and I still get the error.

Inside the code it looks like this:

```rust
use dotenv::dotenv;

async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    dotenv().ok();

    let my_env_var= std::env::var("MY_ENV_VAR").expect("MY_ENV_VAR must be set.");
    ...
}
```

And of course it works perfectly fine with `cargo run`.

How could I run the generated binary and ensure that .env file is read correctly? (using a mac mini)

NB: I use `open {binary name}` to open the binary

Comment: It probably searches for the file in current working directory?

Comment: that's why I added the .env file in the working directory but it didn't work

Comment: each row in the .env file looks like `MY_ENV_VAR = "sometext"`

Comment: I'm not sure what `open` does (I'm not a macos guy) but since Rust produces a binary can't you just run it directly? Just do `{binary name}` in terminal? It looks like this `open` messes with working dir, maybe?

Comment: Didn't see your comment, I indeed tried opening it directly and it's in fact working! Well thanks anyway, you might want to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, I think `open` messes with the working directory. I don't know why, and what it does exactly (some macos expert can elaborate on this), but it shouldn't matter. That's because Rust produces an executable binary. This means you don't need to do

```
open {binary name}
```

you can simply do

```
{binary name}
```

in terminal and it should work without any issues.